# Filter out negative integers from an array PHP

Tags: php, array-filter

I'm trying to remove all negative integers from the following array :

```
$array = array([-122,121,-124,124,-121,122,-122,124,-121,124,-122,125,-121,121,-123,122,-124,120]);
```

I've tried the following, it's not working as I don't really understand how `array_filter` works  :

```
function positive($var) {
  if ($var >= 0) {
    return $var;
  }
}

print_r(array_filter($array, positive($var)));
```

How would I send each value to the `positive` function? Or is there a better way of doing this? `array_walk` or `array_map` maybe?

Comment: Take a look at [function.array-filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: That's what I'm already using. I just don't understand how to send the value to the callback function?

Comment: You can do with array_filter here, not understanding it fully is not an issue, you can learn more about that function in the PHP manual: https://php.net/array_filter - and a hint: your code is pretty close to the solution, but I leave that little detail to your own findings as I think you will greatly benefit that way.

Comment: _That's what I'm already using.._ I am aware of that but I think you didnt have a look at the docs..so I've googled them for you

Comment: And if you prefer more examples (the manual has examples, too, and comments), you should find it on stackoverflow already, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/11564786/367456 and similar ones, but I would always prefer reading and then applying by myself to get a proof of my own understanding.

Comment: @B001ᛦ I did read the docs I promise ;), but as I'm sure you're aware, the docs on php.net are not always that easy to follow for those of us that aren't PHP gurus.

Comment: Don't think docs on PHP net is for gurus. Like PHP itself , the docs are a community project and written by many different people and they are as good as everbody does with them. Just noting, as you've posted to Stackoverflow which is only as well as good as it's community so perhaps as well only for Q&A gurus you can say for wishful thinking ... .

Comment: @hakre Oh I wasn't knocking php.net, it's an amazing resource, just sometimes it can been a bit tough to follow. That actually wasn't the case this time though, as you can see from the answer below this was entirely my mistake by not declaring the correct array id. :/

Comment: Glad to read that. These things happen all the time ... :) For me it helps reading the docs then so I can double check parameters or return values. But everybody does this a bit differently.

Comment: What about 0 - keep or remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<?php
$array = array([-122,121,-124,124,-121,122,-122,124,-121,124,-122,125,-121,121,-123,122,-124,120]);

function positive($var) 
{
    if ($var >= 0) 
    {
        return true;
    }
}

print_r(array_filter($array[0], 'positive'));
```

You had to pass `$array[0]` as parameter to modify array. You have declared array with array in first element `array([-122,...,-124,120]);` so to filter array you need to pass `$array[0]`.

Output is:

```
Array ( [1] => 121 [3] => 124 [5] => 122 [7] => 124 [9] => 124 [11] => 125 [13] => 121 [15] => 122 [17] => 120 )
```

Comment: Ahh now I feel stupid... Thanks man ;)

Comment: @spice It happens sometimes when tired

Comment: Don't feel stupid, it's a well description, it just helped you to put the missing links together. As has been commented before: Your code already was *pretty* close.

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence but it's always a bit embarrassing when you miss something so obvious. Need more coffee :)

Comment: Alexey, why did you put function positive under ``''``, when you stated up that you need to put $var into function

Answer (score 4):

The [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) states:

> array array_filter ( array $array [, callable $callback [, int $flag =
>   0 ]] )
>
> Iterates over each value in the array passing them to the callback
>   function. If the callback function returns true, the current value
>   from array is returned into the result array. Array keys are
>   preserved.

Use a callback that tests for a positive value:

```
$array = [-122,121,-124,124,-121,122,-122,124,-121,124,-122,125,-121,121,-123,122,-124,120];
$positive_integers = array_filter($array, function($value) {
    return $value > 0;
});
```